# Swift how to have a TableView of hashs

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

New to swift and mobile at all.
Created the default Master project in Xcode and trying to have a table (`tableView`) of categories where each category has an int next to it

House 1

Child 4

Food  5

That's it. 
The default cells are just time stamp like so

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

I presume I will want a hash But i can't even set something other than a timestamp in that field

tried

```
newManagedObject.setValue(1, forKey: "timeStamp")
```

instead of

```
newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate.date(), forKey: "timeStamp")
```

get an error

> Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "timeStamp"; desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFNumber; value = 1.'

just FYI, my master controller is like so

```
MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

Comment: Why do you need a hash? What would you di with it?

Comment: hi @zaph thanks for the reply. I want to display a counter for each category. So i need the category name and it's current counter.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding of the word "hash". In some languages a dictionary is called a hash, in Swift they are the 'Dictionary' class and in Objective-C the `NSDictionary` class.